# Adding dependencies to buildSrc for source files in buildSrc

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I added the buildSrc folder to my android project to use kotlin-dsl in my gradle scripts. Now I want to add a kotlin file to buildSrc main containing functions, that I´ll use in gradle .kts scripts (buildSrc -> src -> main -> kotlin -> TheFile.kt). In one of them I´d like to use `com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension`. I see that this would be available in `com.android.tools.build:gradle:x`. How can I include such dependencies to the buildSrc folder? My build.gradle.kts currently looks like this:

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.`kotlin-dsl`

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the 'dependencies' block and include the `com.android.tools.build:gradle:<VERSION>` dependency there:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.tools.build:gradle:<VERSION>")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put any .kt file to BuildSrc/src/main/kotlin directory.

Let say TheFile.kt with

```
object Config {

   val myStringValue : String = "my string value"
   val myIntValue : Int = 666

   fun myFunction() : Int {
      return 555
   }
}
```

and now you can use this values in any build.gradle.kts like

```
something = Config.myStringValue
somethingelse = Config.myIntVale
someresult = Config.MyFunction()
```

Check [Android Studio 3.2+ Kotlin DSL Gradle config boilerplate](https://gitlab.com/gLush/kotlindslandroidbuildscripts)

Comment: Quite useless answer. My problem is that I want to import com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension in buildSrc -> src -> main -> kotlin, so need a hint how to do dependency management in buildSrc to be able to do that